# No funciona Continue For en VBA Excel

Tags: excel, bucle-for, vba

Buen día, espero que se encuentren bien. Tengo un problema con una macro que estoy haciendo en Excel. Para resumir esa macro les muestro el código de abajo. En resumen, es un ciclo que, dependiendo del valor de la variable contadora, le asigna valores a las variables a, b y c para ejecutar un Bhaskara.

```
Dim Alerta As Boolean
Dim i As Byte
Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double

Alerta = True

'EVALUACIÓN DE VALORES
For i = 1 To 5
    
    Select Case i
    
    'TIPO 1 Y 3
    Case 1, 3
        a = 1.3
        b = 2
        c = -4
    
    'TIPO 4
    Case 4
        
        If Alerta = True Then Exit For
        
        a = 1
        b = 0
        c = -3
    
    'TIPO 2 Y 5
    Case 2, 5
        a = 3
        b = 0.345
        c = -80
    End Select
    
    'ANÁLISIS DE BHASKARA
    Call Bhaskara(a, b, c)
    
Next
```

La cuestión es esta, agregué una variable Alerta. Si esa variable es igual a False, el ciclo se realiza normalmente. Y si la variable es igual a True quiero que NO ejecute Bhaskara para i=4. Para resolver ese problema, puse la siguiente línea en i=4:

```
If Alerta = True Then Exit For
```

El problema con esa línea es que si Alerta=True, me corta el ciclo para i=4 pero también para i=5, y yo sí quiero que ejecute Bhaskara para i=5. Investigando, encontré que existe el Continue For, que me permitiría saltear el i=4 y continuar con el i=5, acción que yo deseo.

```
If Alerta = True Then Continue For
```

No obstante, si lo pongo así tal cual, me salta esta advertencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal y lo necesito dado que en la macro original no tengo la opción de poner un condicional o usar el Exit For. Desde ya agradezco las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza tu condicion alerta para manejar los valores que no quieres que se ejecuten por ejemplo

```
IF i != 4 THEN
    'ANÁLISIS DE BHASKARA
    Call Bhaskara(a, b, c)
END IF
```

De esta forma cuando el ciclo llegue al valor 4 no ejecutará el análisis

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la macro original, la variable i puede alcanzar hasta 20 valores aproximadamente y la variable Alerta en realidad es una variable de tipo Byte que va de 1 a 5. Entonces, por ejemplo, si i=4 y alerta=1 quiero que se haga el análisis pero si i=5 y alerta=3 NO quiero que se haga. Si aplico una estructura como esa me va a quedar algo grande la macro con todas las condiciones en las que quiero que se cumpla y que no se cumpla. Por eso me gustaba la simpleza del Continue For ¿Hay una forma de aplicarlo o sólo puedo aplicar estructuras condicionales?

Comment: Define bien los escenarios y con base en ello realiza una adecuación a tu código.  Si utilizas el CONTINUE o un IF ambos vienen dados por un control sobre el ciclo, por ello te sugiero que analices tu código para definir en base a los criterios como colocar tu condición.

Answer (score 1):

*si la variable es igual a True quiero que NO ejecute Bhaskara para i=4*

No te compliques y pon un if solo antes de llamar a Bhaskara:

```
Dim Alerta As Boolean
Dim i As Byte
Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double

Alerta = True

'EVALUACIÓN DE VALORES
For i = 1 To 5
    
    Select Case i
    
    'TIPO 1 Y 3
    Case 1, 3
        a = 1.3
        b = 2
        c = -4
    
    'TIPO 4
    Case 4
        a = 1
        b = 0
        c = -3
    
    'TIPO 2 Y 5
    Case 2, 5
        a = 3
        b = 0.345
        c = -80
    End Select
    
    'ANÁLISIS DE BHASKARA
    
    If Alerta = True And i = 4 Then
        'no ejecutamos
    Else
        Call Bhaskara(a, b, c)
    End If
Next
```

Fíjate que estamos usando el operador AND, así que **ambas** condiciones deben cumplirse para NO ejecutar Bhaskara. Si Alerta=True **y** la i es cualquier valor distinto a 4, entonces SÍ ejecuta Bhaskara. Si Alerta=False, se ejecutará Bhaskara para cualquier valor de i.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que esto ya llega tarde, pero me lo he encontrado teniendo el mismo problema de que el dichoso "Continue For" me daba error, en mi caso con el ACCESS. No conseguí usarlo. La solución más parecida, aunque menos elegante, que se me ocurrió fue utilizar una etiqueta y un GoTo. Quedando algo así:

```
For i = 1 To 5

miEtiqueta:

'blablablacodigo

if condiciondesalto=true then
i=i+1
goto miEtiqueta
end if

'blablablacodigo

Next i
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).